# Expertise, Big Business, Promote

Tags: phrases

I can't understand the three nouns referred to in the title. They are in different sentences and I could've created two different question, so if it violates the rules, I will move the second part to another question. I've searched many dictionaries but I still have difficulty guessing the meaning.

1. What is the meaning of *big business* and *expertise* in the following sentence?

> For urban Europe, bicycle policy **expertise** has become **big
>   business**. Cities seeking new businesses, tourists, and expats, now
>   consider a vibrant cycling culture an index of health and
>   prosperity.

2. *Promoting sth is high on sth*. Is it a grammatical sentence? I could easily understand if it was *benefits of promoting*.

> **Promoting** the benefits of urban cycling is also high on urban
>    planners’ mobility and environmental sustainability agendas, to solve
>    the structural problems facing cities today.

Comment: thefreedictionary says big business is: "Commercial operations organized and financed on a large scale"  but I can't relate this meaning to expertise,  or this one from thefreelibrary: "Vermont's small breweries are big business."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll preface my answer with a statement that I’m not a native-speaker, so here is my understanding.
Bicycle policy expertise = expertise in bicycle policy (laws and regulations) = special knowledge in that area based on experience. See https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/expertise
Companies with a solid knowledge of bycicle policies become big businesses, because they can create the right product for the market. Right product - good sales - more money - you‘re on top - big business.

Now promoting the benefits is high on ...agendas. Promoting the benefits here means advertising the benefits/making people aware of them. It’s a priority for urban planners (that’s why it’s high on their agendas)because they need to solve structural problems.

Comment: Policy is something which the state is responsible for, right? But the sentence ends with big business, I can't understand how policy results in big business. Maybe because English is my 2nd language I can't hear the meaning of become in this sentence.

Comment: I should say that I fully understood your answer to the second part, and also the clarifying the meaning of expertise. Thank you.

Comment: If it was "led to big business" I didn't have problem but "become big business", it's somehow vague.

Comment: *Some companies make lots of money* [= "big business"] from *being experts in government policies on cycling* [= "bicycle policy expertise"]. This has only recently happened, i.e. the expertise *has developed into* [= "has become"] big business.

Comment: @Chappo sorry for my insistence, what does _being experts in government policies_ mean? Companies introduce or set policies or ...?

Comment: how can you connect the second sentence to the first sentence: 1st one ends with companies and the second one starts with cities.

Comment: @sama In this case, (1) a government adopts public policies the purpose of which is to promote their city through increased bicycle usage, and (b) companies develop expertise in this kind of policy and use their expertise to gain public contracts and make money. NB: if you are having trouble understanding this level of English, our site may not be appropriate for you. Our other site [ell.se] might be better suited for future questions.

Comment: @Chappo yes, I will refer to the other site for future questions.